# How to insert menu from resources to existed menu?

Tags: c++, menu, insert, mfc

Please help to do the subject.

I have main menu from CMainFrame and I need to insert another menu from resouces to main menu.

I've try to use next:

```
m_menu2.LoadMenu( IDR_MENU2 );  
main_menu.GetSubMenu( 1 )->InsertMenu( 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)m_menu2.m_hMenu );
```

But have no effect. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter should include a name for the subitem:

```
m_menu2.LoadMenu( IDR_MENU2 ); 
CMenu *temp = main_menu.GetSubMenu(1);
if (temp)
{
    temp->InsertMenu(0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING | MF_POPUP,
        (UINT_PTR)m_menu2.m_hMenu, "new subitem in main memu");
}
```